# Cleaning up class path, what is the correct approach to avoid this issue in future?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am building a java 12 based project using Gradle as the build tool and all things going well until I shared code on the repo for another dev to have a look. In inadvertently it seems I have put a lot of jars in the classpath as dependencies in the project

[image]

[image]

admittedly this is going to look awful I'm sure to some more competent developers out there but I have not done this before so hence my likely rookie mistake here. What I'm looking to understand most is *how* this came to be, i.e. I don't recall adding these dependencies in to the classpath myself so I assume gradle did it for me.

So some questions I have around this are

- Did I do this the right way? Should I be lettinggradle handle my classpath updates like that? (I am assuming it was gradle because the folder paths are gradle based mostly)
- Confirm it was not actually eclipse that did this somehow and I'm misleading myself to believe it was gradle
- How do I *correctly* avoid this issue in the future to stop other people taking the code having issues like this again? Do I put better clarifications in the gradle script somewhere, or do I not ship with all the dependencies listed so the next user pulls them all down themselves?
- Is this actually an issue? I'm presuming it is an issue because of my own personal drive folder structure being put in place but was there some checkbox I missed maybe that would've set this up the right way without picking up the personal folder structure? Like perhaps a reference to a system environment variable for the first component to get to '.gradle'
- When I build my application to ship it, will these references or jars be compiled into the final jar that I produce thus when it's on another machine this folder setup etc won't be an issue?

Am fully willing to admit there are some components running here that I don't understand but this one sneaked up on me so I've likely long missed where I made that mistake thus identifying how I did it kind've hard for me

EDIT: gradle build script

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.9.4'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'com.bisit'
version '0.1.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 12

javafx {
    version = "12"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'com.bisit.App'

dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2')

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.4.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.12.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations
    compile group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '17.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.clojure/java.jdbc
    compile group: 'org.clojure', name: 'java.jdbc', version: '0.7.10'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.28.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.4.1.jre12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.17'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker
    compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.29'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-core
    compile group: 'com.openhtmltopdf', name: 'openhtmltopdf-core', version: '1.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.openhtmltopdf/openhtmltopdf-pdfbox
    compile group: 'com.openhtmltopdf', name: 'openhtmltopdf-pdfbox', version: '1.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '6.0.0.Alpha2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    runtimeOnly group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.199'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '4.1.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.0'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.bisit.Launcher'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'xmlanalyser'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    if (System.getProperty('DEBUG', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs '-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9099'
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse most likely got this information from the Gradle build script, but can't be sure without seeing it. As for whether or not this is a problem, that would be determined by which dependencies you need and meant to have. Note that declaring a dependency also pulls in all _transitive_ dependencies, recursively.

Comment: added the gradle script in total there. so if thats the case does that mean i incorrectly uploaded the dependencies to github and thats why the other team member got dependencies pointing at my local file drive?